# constructor of class derived from std::string not compiling

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

On chapter 2, page 42 of Effective C++, the author gives an example of deriving a class from `std::string` (which has a non-virtual destructor), and then `delete`ing an instance of the derived class through a base pointer, and how this is undefined behavior.

This is fine and all, but the example he gives doesn't even compile, and for a completely unrelated reason. Here, I have reproduced the code from the book as closely as possible for a minimal working example:

```
#include <string>
#include <new>

class SpecialString: public std::string{};

int main(){
  SpecialString *pss = new SpecialString("Impending Doom");
  std::string *ps = pss;
  delete ps;
  return 0;
}
```

However, the line constructing the `SpecialString` does not compile on my GCC because it is trying to convert the `const char*` `"Impending Doom"` to a `const SpecialString&`, instead of calling `std::string(const char*)`, which is what I'm guessing the book expects it to do. Is there something wrong with my assumption here?

Comment: Does `SpecialString` really not implement any constructors or use any using statements?

Comment: yeah, I thought about that; by not implementing anything, I allowed my compiler to implement the default constructor and default copy constructor, and the latter is causing the issue I am guessing. The book simply skipped the implementation of the `SpecialString` class. Does this mean in order to construct `SpecialStrings` with `const char*`s, I have to manually implement it, even though that functionality is supported by the base class `SpecialString` is derived from?

Comment: @xdavidliu Pre-C++11 yes. Now you can use [*inheriting constructors*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration). BTW most of the code you posted is irrelevant.

Comment: @xdavidliu: "*This is fine and all, but the example he gives doesn't even compile*" That's because it's not a complete example. Hence the `...` part, which is basically "insert appropriate code here." Meyers's point is that there is *nothing* you can put in that class which will stop the example from being undefined behavior. It's ultimately not clear what it is you're asking about. Do you want to know how to make such a derived class "work"?

Comment: my question was unrelated to the undefined behavior Meyers was talking about, as I explained in the original; it was simply asking why I couldn't construct `SpecialString` using a `const char*`. The fact that the unimplemented part was `...` made me assume that I could get away with just leaving it blank, and it would still at least compile and illustrate the author's point. I'm pretty happy with the first three commenters though in terms of answering what I originally asked.